# Changing file size when exporting Layout as PDF using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, print-composer, pdf, file-size

I have a plugin that exports a pdf of a layout. Up to QGIS 3.18 the file size was typically about 2.7MB, since moving to 3.20.1 it has increased to about 17MB for exactly the same layout and data. I can see nothing in the release notes about changes to the export function.

Reinstalling 3.18 resulted in the file size returning to about 2.7MB. Has anyone else experienced this change or can anyone suggest what might be causing it?

Comment: Are your settings in the PDF dialog box the same in both cases, in particular those for resolution, rasterize map and simplify geometries.  If you are creating geospatial PDFs are the layers settings the same?

Comment: Have you checked the page size of the exported PDF?

Comment: The data are exported using a plugin written in Python which calls the exportToPdf() function using the default settings, which I have not changed. I'm also using exactly the same template.I think the default resolution is 300dpi, which is what I'm using.